# How many IT Majors must be American?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a class of $40$ students who are either IT Majors or Americans, there are $29$ IT majors and $32$ Americans. How many IT Majors must be American?

I SOMEHOW know how to solve this problem but what confuses me is that the universal value is $40$. But $29 + 32 = 61$ which is above $40$. How is this even possible?

Comment: I feel it's a bit strange it says "either...or" as I thought this indicates an exclusive or, which here it is clearly not.

Answer (score 2):

The point of this problem is that some people must be both IT majors AND American. Otherwise, as you observe, the sum doesn't work out. If no IT majors are American, then there are at least $29+32=61$ people in the class. This is too many. If there is one American IT major, then we are double counting her, so we subtract one to correct for this: there are at least $29+32-1=60$ people. This is still too many, so there has to be more than one American IT major. If there are ten American IT majors, we are double counting ten people, so we subtract ten to make up for it: there are at least $29+32-10=51$ people in the class, *still* too many. With a little thought, you can figure out the smallest number $n$ of people who have to be both American and IT majors, so that $29+32-n\leq 40$.

Comment: thank you, now I understand more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Because some peoples (21 in this case) are both IT majors and Americans.

Problem just tells you that 29 are IT majors, it doesn't say that 29 are  IT majors but not American.

Key point is to understand there are peoples in both the sets.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question is unfortunate.  The expression "who are either IT majors or Americans" suggests that the students are either IT majors or Americans, but not both.  Since there are only $40$ students in the class, that cannot be the case and could be a source of confusion.  The word "either" should be removed.

Let $A$ be the set of Americans; let $I$ be the set of IT majors.  If we add the number of Americans to the number of IT majors, then we count each American IT major twice, once as an American and once as an IT major.  Thus, to find the number of people in the class, we must subtract the number of people who are both American and an IT major from the sum of the number of Americans and the number of IT majors in the class.
$$|A \cup I| = |A| + |I| - |A \cap I| \tag{1}$$
What we wish to find is the number of people who are American IT majors.  Hence, we must solve equation 1 for $|A \cap I|$, which yields
$$|A \cap I| = |A| + |I| - |A \cup I| \tag{2}$$
We were given that $|A| = 32$, $|I| = 29$, and $|A \cup I| = 40$.  Substituting those values into equation 2 yields the desired result.

**Note:** Equation 1 is an application of the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to two sets.

Answer (score 0):

## Picture!

$x$ is the number of people who are both American and IT majors.

[image: Venn diagram]